# Lower priority for specific pages

Tags: sitemap, pagerank

I have some documents that are not as important and I would like to have a lower priority for them.

If I generate a sitemap I can set the priority for these pages to a lower value, e.g. 0.1. According to the official spec (http://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html) the default is 0.5 so if I don't specify a priority it should be considered the default, i.e. 0.5.

What if I would only include the pages that need tweaking in the sitemap and leave out all other pages on the site. What would that do to the ranking of the "normal" pages and the ranking of the site?

Answer (score 1):

The number inside the priority tags is supposed to represent the relative priority of each URL you’ve listed, so therefore it only goes from 0.0 to 1.0, with 1.0 being the most important.

But, you have a paradox there. If something is not so important, it can't affect ranking.

Comment: What I'm trying to ask is what would happen if I only have a subset of my site represented in the site map.